# команда tee (linux) вывод в терминале строкой ниже

Tags: linux, вывод, терминал

`program | tee -a file.txt`

`program` при выполнении выводит в терминале служебную информацию о процессе выполнения на следующей строке, `tee` тоже начинает с той же строки вывод, в результате визуально в терминале вывод `tee` накладывается на вывод служебной информации.
Нет ли какого способа сделать вывод `tee` всё тоже самое, только начиная с 1 строки ниже? Ну или решить это каким-то аналогом другой команды? Спасибо

Comment: Ну так вставьте *tail -n+1* между. *+* важен!

Answer (score 2):

вставить в начало потока символ перевода строки можно, например, так:

```
$ программа | cat <(echo) - | другая-программа
```

Comment: при `program | cat <(echo) - | tee -a file.txt` пустая строка появилась, да. Но осталось все тоже самое, что и было, просто выше всего вставилась пустая строка, а служ.инфа первой программы пошла после пустой строки (а не в пустой строке выше, как ожидалось). возможно я недопонял и не правильно сделал ..

Comment: ну, задержку попробуйте добавить. что-нибудь типа `... | { sleep 0.5; cat <(echo) -; } | ...` (может, вашей программе и больше надо, чем пол-секунды). но вообще то, чем вы занимаетесь — «гиблое дело»: вывод вашей программы как-то нелогично устроен. пытаясь подстроиться под неё тем способом, который вы зачем-то выбрали, вы, с моей точки зрения, напрасно тратите своё время.

Comment: я поэкспериментирую, спасибо. с программой все в порядке, это просто моя инициатива воткнуть tee туда, куда она не планировалась разработчиком.

Comment: под нелогичностью я подразумевал: 1. программа что-то выводит в stdout. этих строк запросто может быть столько, чтобы не уместиться в видимой области. 2. одновременно программа (вероятно, через curses или как-то ещё) выводит какую-то диагностическую информацию в определённую строку экрана. но эта строка ведь может «уехать» из области видимости (см. пункт 1). // в общем, скрестили ужа с ежом. логично либо выводить одну (или сколько требуется) обновляемую строку, либо нормально писать всё в stdout.

Comment: И это переносимо в любой командной оболочке?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin может сначала перенаправить все в stdut? program &>1 (только в баше )